# Issue starting Greenplum as service

Tags: linux, systemd, greenplum, reboot, systemctl

Greenplum start command asking for prompt in systemd service even after providing option not to prompt. Same command runs directly without prompt.

```
[Unit]
Description=Greenplum daemon
[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment
EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/greenplum
User=gpadmin
Group=gpadmin
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "source /opt/greenplum-db-6-6.11.2/greenplum_path.sh";/opt/greenplum-db-6-6.11.2/bin/gpstart -a -l /home/gpadmin/gpAdminLogs -d /greenplum/master/gpseg-1
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5s
PrivateTmp=true
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Logs --
Nov 18 05:30:05 : Continue with Greenplum instance startup Yy|Nn (default=N):
Nov 18 05:30:05 : > 20201118:05:30:05:023285 gpstart:gplum-master:gpadmin-[CRITICAL]:-gpstart failed. (Reason='EOF when reading a line') exiting
Nov 18 05:30:05 : greenplum.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT

Comment: Try changing WantedBy to "default.target", adding "After=network.target" to the Unit section, and switch to gpadmin. su -l gpadmin -c "source ~/.bashrc; gpstart -a"

Comment: @JonRoberts It worked. Now logs show database is started. But the service status is inactive(dead). Any idea on this..? Also can you please elaborate why should I change WantedBy to "default.target", adding "After=network.target" to the Unit section